# How can I set an upper limit on mass imbalance in Fluent?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cfd

I studied a paper about simulation of turbines using Fluent that included the following sentence, which I don't understand:

> All  converged solutions  had  a  mass imbalance  of less  than 
>   0.3%

What does the mass imbalance of converged solutions refer to?

How can I ensure this condition is met in Fluent?

Answer (score 5):

Mass imbalance is a measure of the error in the solution.  You would typically set the limit for this in the "Solution Controls" section of the inputs (if using the GUI).  For mass imbalance, set the tolerance for residuals on the continuity equation.  The solver will keep iterating until it finds a solution that satisfies all your residual tolerances, or until it reaches the limit of iterations that you set.

Comment: Thanks.
I didn't understood your following sentences:
"For mass imbalance, set the tolerance for residuals on the continuity equation."
According your above statement, How i must set this in Fluent? Please give me trajectory in Fluent.

Comment: In the GUI, click on "Solution Controls", then look for the continuity equation box.  The default tolerance is usually 0.001 I think.

Comment: Thanks.
In Fluent, there is Solution Controls option but i don't see this tolerance part in that!!!

Comment: Depending on whether you're doing a pressure-based solution or a density-based one, the option may be for density residual tolerance.  Do you at least see tolerance settings for various residuals?  I.e. energy, momentum, etc.?

Comment: I see as follows:

http://upsara.com/images/eljd_capture33.jpg

there is not any tolerance settings.

Comment: Hmm, this looks different from my version of Fluent.  Best to check the documentation for your version; look for residual tolerance or similar.  [This is what I have](http://aerojet.engr.ucdavis.edu/fluenthelp/html/ug/node1023.htm)